# public value struct in WinRT

Tags: directx, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Why "public value struct" can not have any method or constructor but "value struct" can?
How to write structs like "Vector3" in WinRT component library and use it in another WinRT application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a struct as "public", you're declaring it as a windows runtime structure.  Structs in the windows runtime are value types.  They cannot have methods (or constructors).

They are also marshaled by value which may not be what you want.

You probably would want to create a class instead of a struct.

Comment: +1. However, from performance point of view splitting data and methods into a struct and a class may be better than having a class in this case (i.e., `Vector3`). By the way, are structs and classes in WinRT similar to .NET with respect that only structs can be allocated on stack (and, thus, faster)?

Comment: Structs are value types and thus are usually only allocated on the stack, but there are some circumstances where they'll be allocated on the heap (arrays of structs, for examples).  But because they're value types, they're passed by value - that means if you write an API that takes a struct, the struct contents are copied on the stack to the callee.  That can be very expensive.

Comment: So, the situation is similar in .NET and WinRT. Allocation of structs is cheaper (the difference should be even greater, because allocation on managed heap is much cheaper), and copying is more expensive than for reference types, especially if size is large. Profiling should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Valuetypes/structs are mapped as "blocks" of memory much like the traditional C struct rather than the implementation that .Net has i.e.: which can contain fields and methods..

So the value types needs to only have fields in them or a constructor.

You will need to split the Vector3 into two parts, one with the data perhaps called Vector3Data with Vector3 having all the methods you need to manipulate it.

Comment: Value types can't have constructors.

Comment: This is a restriction imposed (sensibility), in the language, for example C# but other languages don't impose this restriction.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx

Comment: @spgennard AFAK, this is a restriction of WinRT for public value types. C# allows constructors with parameters and always creates parameterless constructor. The restriction which you mentioned says that in C# it is not possible to explicitly declare a constructor without parameters.

Comment: Some interesting feature proposal related to the topic: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2287920-customize-winrt-projections-in-the-target-language